# WordPress i18n-friendly preg_replace post title

Tags: title, localization, private

I've stripped `Private:` and `Protected:` from my custom post title that are forced to be private. I'm using [CSS Tricks' snippet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-privateprotected-from-post-titles/) for doing so:

```
function the_title_trim($title) {

    if( is_admin() )
       return $title;

    $title = esc_attr($title);

    $findthese = array(
        '#Protected:#',
        '#Private:#'
    );

    $replacewith = array(
        '', // What to replace "Protected:" with
        '' // What to replace "Private:" with
    );
    global $post;
    if( 'mycpt' === get_post_type($post) ) {
       $title = preg_replace( $findthese, $replacewith, $title );
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter('the_title', 'the_title_trim');
```

It works fine as expected.

But recently when I switched to a different language, I found it's not working. And you can guess easily that, the `$findthese` array is failing to match any other language's strings for those specified.

How can I use `preg_replace()` for stripping the texts, that supports i18n strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the [`protected_title_format`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a138374ec8e4034a70b8fcd6622e6f1fe1bfaf82/wp-includes/post-template.php#L119-L130) and [`private_title_format`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a138374ec8e4034a70b8fcd6622e6f1fe1bfaf82/wp-includes/post-template.php#L134-L145) filters, available since WordPress version 2.8:

```
 add_filter( 'protected_title_format', 'wpse_pure_title', 10, 2 );
 add_filter( 'private_title_format',   'wpse_pure_title', 10, 2 );

 function wpse_pure_title( $format, \WP_Post $post )
 {
    return  'mycpt' === get_post_type( $post ) ? '%s' : $format;
 }
```

to get rid of the "Private:" and "Protected:" parts on the front-end for the `mycpt` post type.

We don't need a `is_admin()` check here, because these filters [only run](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a138374ec8e4034a70b8fcd6622e6f1fe1bfaf82/wp-includes/post-template.php#L116) in  the front-end.

Comment: That's perfect. +1